# How to change the color of Razer Mamba?

Tags: drivers, razer-mouse

I just bought a *Razer Mamba* and I was in the process of configuring it when I noticed that the *Lighting and Power* tab was just *Lighting*, and didn't give me the option to change anything.

I've seen YouTube videos and I'm wondering how to get the same Razer Configuration program as all these other people. I went to the Razer site and downloaded the most recent drivers but no help there.

Something is missing and I don't know what.

I'm running Windows 7.

Comment: You need to provide more details about your driver version, its possible you don't have the right or latest version.

Comment: Delphy can you provide a screenshot and information about the drivers you have installed?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply I'll get all that info to you when I get home.

Comment: This question can be ignored I found out the vendor I went to didn't know there were two different models and I got the old Mamba... returned it and the new one is on the way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the [Razer Mamba new edition](http://store.razerzone.com/store/razerusa/en_US/pd/productID.231103000) can change colours. Be sure you have the right version and the appropriate synapse manager from Razer Zone. (I assume you need the Mamba 2012 drivers)

Comment: If I actually did have a problem this is the answer, thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

That feature requires a 2012 4g Razer Mamba.  If your device is older than that, the feature is unavailable.